# What to use instead of 'pause' after the 'goto' command?

Tags: batch-file, notepad

I'm making a "how-to" batch file in [Notepad](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Notepad_%28software%29). I'm trying to demonstrate the `goto` command, and I want to like carry on. I tried `pause`, but then I realized that wouldn't work, so I don't know what to do. This is that part of my code...

```
:start
echo This is  the goto command
goto:start
pause 
cls
echo That is the product of the goto command
```

The `pause` and `cls` is what I tried.

Comment: What does "I want to like carry on" mean? You tried `pause` and `cls` to do what?

Comment: I mean like I want to carry on doing my "tutorial" but I don't know how to keep the program open and move on to the next thing

Comment: you can't. `goto start` will go to `:start`. Every time. They call it "an endless loop".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To demonstrate a simple unconditional `goto`command, this will do better:

```
echo this is before
goto :continue
echo this line is never reached.
:continue
echo this is after the "goto"
```

(this is a "forward" jump. Your's was a "backward" jump)